# Problems with Editor when i do git commit

Tags: windows, git

In my message for commit, I'm trying to use the guidelines:

1º Line - summary with <80char

2º Line - space

3º Line - The body message start here

In console, I'm doing this:

**git commit**

then the editor opens and i write my message that i want to following the guidelines
I save and then close the editor.

**i return the console and it give me the error:**

```
error: There was a problem with the editor '"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe" fileeditor'.

Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you are saying i can assume that you are using git extension on windows, i think that your issue is related to a bad configuration, configure the default text editor in the configuration pane of git extension .

Otherwise you can commit without having the editor prompted each time in this way :

```
git commit -m "Your commit message"
```

If you want to have a multiline message you can break the line with a backslash :

```
git commit -m "1º Line - summary with <80char \
2º Line - space \
3º Line - The body message start here"
```

Comment: how i can configure it? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Set the default text editor for git with (specify the editor of you choice):

```
git config --global core.editor "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

Answer (score -1):

I suspect this is because your text editor does not exit with status code 0 (indicating success, and no error). What text editor are you using and did you quit the text editor cleanly?

Comment: I'm not sure. In global settings i have for editor the path: "C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe" fileeditor